# Overloaded function that excepts typed function never chooses fallback implementation (rest params)

Tags: typescript

First, let me note that I'm using TypeScript 2.9.2 as we're waiting for 3.1 before we upgrade again.

I have a function that wraps the function passed, returning a function that is identical to the one passed, but with a first parameter added and a different return type. Here's a simple reproduction of the issue:

```
interface Foo<T> {
    foo: string
    value: T
}

type GetFoo1<T, R> = (t: T) => Foo<R>;
type GetFooAny<R> = (...args: any[]) => Foo<R>;
type OtherFoo1<T> = (other: boolean, t: T) => Foo<void>;
type OtherFooAny = (other: boolean, ...args: any[]) => Foo<void>;

function f<T, R>(fn: GetFoo1<T, R>): OtherFoo1<T>;
function f<R>(fn: GetFooAny<R>): OtherFooAny {
    return (other: boolean, ...args: any[]) => {
        return {foo: 'foo', value: void 0};
    };
}
const test1 = (a: string): Foo<boolean> => ({foo: 'foo', value: true});
const testAny = (a: string, b: number) => ({foo: 'foo', value: false});

// Yay
const foo1 = f(test1);

// Error
const fooAny = f(testAny);
```

I'm not sure why but this will never choose the fallback implementation based on types, unless I coerce the type. E.g.

```
const fooAny = f(testAny as GetFooAny<boolean>);
```

or

```
const testAny: GetFooAny<boolean> =
  (a: string, b: number) => ({foo: 'foo', value: false});
const fooAny = f(testAny);
```

Will work.

The reason I'm going through this trouble is that I want the types of arguments of `GetFoo*` to flow through to `OtherFoo*`. This works, but the fact that I have to coerce or specifically add types makes me feel like I'm doing this incorrectly.

**Edit:** In fact, coercing does not work correctly either. It gets rid of the errors, but the return type ends up being `OtherFoo1<any>` instead of `OtherFooAny`. TypeScript refuses to use the fallback implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TypeScript refuses to use the fallback implementation.

Yes, [this is in the FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-am-i-getting-supplied-parameters-do-not-match-any-signature-error).

In order to participate in overload resolution, the signature must be declared as overload, even if it's exactly the same as the implementation signature.

```
function f<T, R>(fn: GetFoo1<T, R>): OtherFoo1<T>;
function f<R>(fn: GetFooAny<R>): OtherFooAny;
function f<R>(fn: GetFooAny<R>): OtherFooAny {
    return (other: boolean, ...args: any[]) => {
        return {foo: 'foo', value: void 0};
    };
}
```

Comment: I'm so embarrassed. Thank you for humoring me!

Comment: No need to be embarrassed, the FAQ is really big and only linked from the [wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki) which is not the most obvious place to look